# Subsection not showing up in toc

Tags: table-of-contents

I am including chapters (comprised of sections and subsections) in a main file and then compiling the entire file from there. I am using a `"thesis.cls"` file provided to me. The only problem is that the subsections inside the chapters do not show up in the table of contents while all the sections do (`introduction` is a chapter and has subsections inside it). Now, I have made sure that the subsections do not have a `*` (i.e., 
`subsection*{methods}`) 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

**Question:**

**Hi...Can some please help me as to how I can make the font size of the subsections the same as that of section? My thesis needs to have the same font throughout...many thanks again**

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Jubobs sorry about that....I have included an example. Will this suffice or should I add anything else? thanks again

Comment: You should link to the `thesis.cls` file, or your question will remain difficult to answer.

Comment: @Jubobs just did it..thanks again for your time

Comment: Errr... that's a lot of code. Simply linking to the file (is it not available online somewhere?) would have been preferable.

Comment: @Jubobs sorry about that..i got it from our administrator...i didnt find it online...can you copy it to a .tex file and check it out if it isn't too much trouble?

Comment: The `tocnosub` option in the first line looks suspicious to me.

Comment: @bombcar You're right: `\if@t@cn@sub
\renewcommand\l@subsection{\@gobbletwo}
\renewcommand\l@subsubsection{\@gobbletwo}
\fi`. Just don't use the `tocnosub` option.

Comment: @user2468702 If you have a different question based on this, it would be much preferred to simply ask a new question with a new MWE.  This question has already been answered.

Comment: @cslstr I just did....please take a look...thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take `tocnosub` out of the first line:

```
\documentclass[noragright,centerchapter,12pt]{thesis}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\author{cat}
\title{cat}
\adviser{cat}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\parindent 1em%

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\chapter{cats}
\section{cats}
\subsection{cats}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you also tell me how I can make the font size of the subsections the same as that of section? My thesis needs to have the same font throughout...many thanks again

Comment: @Jubobs Hi..can you please help me with the above?

Comment: @user2468702 - you should ask a new question for that; we'll need the `thesis.sty` file to find the definition of `\subsection` to make it like `\section`.